# access a function in Javascript with a Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, function, hyperlink

I tried to access a function with a hyperlink (). How can I do that?

```
Aufgabe_Overlay = document.createElement("a");
Aufgabe_Overlay.className = "Aufgabe_Overlay"+anzahl;
content.appendChild(Aufgabe_Overlay);
Aufgabe_Overlay.href = "simpl_Aufgabe.html";
Aufgabe_Overlay.onclick = "update_active(name)";
document.body.appendChild(Aufgabe_Overlay);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define your click handler in HTML, you give it a text value:

```
<a href="simpl_Aufgabe.html" onclick="update_active(name)">Click me</a>
```

But when you set up your click handler in the code, you need to assign it a function reference, so you need to update your code like shown in the example below:

```
Aufgabe_Overlay.onclick = function() {
  update_active(name); 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `onclick` property needs to be a **function**, not a string.